# Экран в Android

Tags: java, android, activity

1. Как в Android сделать экран, где будет показываться инструкция, как пользоваться приложением. Этот экран должен появиться только при первом запуске. Т.е смысл как при первом запуске приложения wikberis.
2. Как сделать всплывающее окно, которое будет иногда всплывать, где можно оценить приложение или ответить на короткий опрос. Т.е если пользователь не проходил участие в поставлении оценки будет появляться это окно или если пользователь нажал "оценить позже".

Comment: один вопрос должен содержать одну проблему, а не все то, что у вас накопилось. если у вас несколько проблем - задайте несколько вопросов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Экран при первом запуске называется `onBoarding`. Есть куча готовых решений на гитхабе.
Всплывающий `popup` можно потыкать `ShowCase` библиотеки.

[тыц](https://github.com/topics/onboarding?l=java)